# My footer keeps moving after updating other parts of my code. How do i fix this?

Tags: html, css

How do I keep my footer at the bottom of my page? I have searched through stackoverflow and nothing seems to fix it. The footer coninues to move all over the place but never ends up on the bottom Please Help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dereke.css"/>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="Header">
        <p>Ohio State Buckeyes</p>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/6/6f/1000px-Ohio_State_Buckeyes_logo_svg.png/revision/latest?cb=20130425230958" />
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li id="noUD">|</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li id="noUD">|</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="MidBody">
        <div id="leftbody">
            <img src="http://printableteamschedules.com/images/collegefootball/ohiostatebuckeyesfootballschedule.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="rightbody"></div>
        <div id="lowerbody">
            <img src="http://grfx.cstv.com/schools/osu/graphics/facilities/stadium-night-800x325.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I know the problem is in the CSS:

```
    .Header {
    width: calc(100%-16px);
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.Header p {
    color: white;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 70px;
}
.MidBody {
    background-color: #141414;
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;

}
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -3em;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#leftbody {
    width: 49%;
    height: 425px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#leftbody img {
    width: 490px;
    height: 420px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
#rightbody {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 49%;
    height: 425px;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#lowerbody {
    width: 99%;
    height: 49%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 432px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    postion: relative;
}
#lowerbody img {
    width: 800px;
    height: 325px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#navbar {
    width: 350px;
    color: #F8F8F2;
    font-family: Arial Black;
    margin: -35px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 10px;
}
#noUD {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo img {
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "updating parts of your code"? Can you provide a live demo or fiddle? Btw: It's invalid to declare the same `id` on two elements, though that's unlikely to cause the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `position: absolute;` on `.MidBody`, `#rightbody`, and `#leftbody`, which removes them from the document flow and allows the footer to drift up to the navigation links. Change these to `position: relative;` and remove the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` attributes from them, as these only apply to `position: absolute` elements.

You also misspelled `position` in `#lowerbody`.

Additionally, the static `height` property set on `.MidBody`, and the `margin-top: 432px;` on the `#lowerbody` are causing them to display past your `.footer` element.

Fixing these things will drop the footer to the bottom of the page (but you'll still have many other formatting problems you'll need to attend to). You can use this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wehokehiwu/edit?html,css) I set up to continue testing your page formatting until it looks how you want it to.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Im still new just starting practicing creating a layout. But I really appreciate it!

Comment: I changed all that now my rightbody is diagonal from my left body i need them side by side. Is it my syntax?

Comment: Yes, `#rightbody` and `#leftbody` should be contained in another `div` and set to 50% width each (to separate them from `#lowerbody`). Optionally, you can look into media queries to make the layout work on smaller screens also.

Comment: Play with the margins on the `#*body` elements to stop one from dropping to the next row.

Comment: Thanks again. Makes sense!